# Incidence rates with weights and confidence intervals

Tags: r, data.table

Say you have sample data,

```
data = data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
start=c(58,58,59,29,28,38,53,57,40,33,37,43,54,46,37,60,39),
stop=c(66,71,65,76,72,79,67,79,67,79,80,61,72,74,74,61,76),
event=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
weight=c(617,906,993,974,445,201,971,451,633,984,650,587,784,764,888,359,897))
```

I wish to estimate the incidence of 'event' which is the number of events divided by the person years calculated by: sum(stop-start). I can do it simply by hand. But what if I wish to account for population-level sample weight? I wish to estimate incidence using the 'weight' to get a point estimate and 95% confidence interval.

Comment: Do you need `library(dplyr); data %>% mutate(new = weight * (stop - start))`

Comment: @akrun thanks so much I don't think so because I think I will get wrong standard errors

Comment: Can you please update the post with the expected output. thanks

Comment: @bvowe Do you have a solution in the meantime? I’m struggling calculating IR after weighting. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629786/weighted-incidence-density